# Objective C: uint32_t stored as String, need to read as uint32_t

Tags: objective-c, uicolor, uint32

I am storing color values in a database for an iPad app that needs a legend with colors in it.  Each entry has it's own color value, derived from a hex value.  Basically, my colors all look like this: 0X######.  I have functions that can take this value, as a uint32_t, and turn it into the color I need.  However, I store the value as a String.

What I need to do is convert this string to a uint32_t.  I need "0X######" to equal 0X######, if that makes sense.  I know this might not be possible, in which case I'll have to find another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSScanner` for this.

```
NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"0XAABBCC"];
uint32_t val;
[scanner scanHexLongLong:&val];
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this code this will worked in my code,

```
NSScanner * scannered = [NSScanner scannerWithString:colorHex];

    uint32_t scanedVal;
    [scannered scanHexLongLong:(unsigned long long *)&scanedVal];
    NSLog(@"scanner _____%u",scanedVal);
```